# Reverse a dictionary from <Parent, IEnumerable<Child>> to <Child, IEnumerable<Parent>>

Tags: c#, linq

Given an enumerable of `Parent` where each entry holds an `IEnumerable` of `Child` objects

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Parent, IEnumerable<Child>>>
```

I want to reverse it so it is an `IEnumerable` of `Child` where each entry holds an `IEnumerable` of `Parent` objects.

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Child, IEnumerable<Parent>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

```cs
source
    .SelectMany(
        x => x.Value,
        (k, v) => new
        {
            Child = k.v,
            Parent = k.Key
        })
    .GroupBy(
        keySelector: x => x.Child,
        elementSelector: x => x.Parent)
    .ToDictionary(
        keySelector: x => x.Key,
        elementSelector: x => x.AsEnumerable());
```